# Python: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python

My code looks like this:

```
for index, row in dfspread.iterrows():  
    if row['Bin'] == 'A':
        max_exp = []
        gammastar = []
        for idx,rw in df_b.iterrows():
            exp = rw['Proba-a']*(rw['gamma']*row['spread']*(1+f)-(f+f))
            max_exp.append(float(exp))
            exp_gain_max = max(max_exp)
            gammastar = ((exp_gain_max) + f+f)/(rw['Proba-a']*row['spread']*(1+f))
            dfspread.at[index,'gamma*']= gammastar
```

I have the error at the line  `gammastar = ((exp_gain_max) + f+f)/(rw['Proba-a']*row['spread']*(1+f))`, exp_gain_max is a number like: 7.560439039725613e-10, f= 0.00000001, spread= 0.003 and proba-a is a number like 0.0045. Any idea why I constantly have this issue?? Thanks!

Comment: Are there rows with missing values for `rw['Proba-a']` or `row['spread']`? (maybe add a print statement before the `gammastart = ...` line for these variables, so you see where it errors). And where does `f` come from? (I'm asuming f != -1?)

Comment: Do you have some sample data of `dfspread` and `df_b`?

Comment: f is just a value, f= 0.000001 and is defined right before the loop...

Comment: I overlooked the `f`. Did you check/print the variables in the for-loop at the loop where the error occurs?